# Perl no warnings 'experimental' on old perl

Tags: perl, warnings

I have a piece of code which uses a lot of experimental (`when`, `smartmatch`, `given`) features, it's not my code, and I don't want to see a lot of warnings about experimental features. So I added `no warnings 'experimental';` to this code. But `experimental` category was added only in perl 5.18 so my code dies in older perls:

> Unknown warnings category 'experimental'

How can I disable this warnings and do not break my code in older perls?

Comment: @Сухой27, this code will disable warnings inside BEGIN block

Comment: I don't understand the question: Your code written for some old version of Perl is running under a newer version of Perl, even if those features marked "experimental" may work differently under that version. Then you want to silence those warnings for a version of Perl that is newer(?) than the version for which that code was written, and you also want to run that code for even newer versions of Perl? It seems you are heading for trouble! From "man perlpolicy": "*If something in the Perl core is marked as experimental, we may change its behaviour, deprecate or remove it without notice.*"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try [if](https://metacpan.org/pod/if):

```
no if ($] >= 5.018), 'warnings' => 'experimental';
```

Answer (score 10):

Try installing and using the [experimental](https://metacpan.org/pod/experimental) module. On older perls it will do nothing, and on newer perls it will disable the warnings.

```
use experimental qw(smartmatch switch);
```

Comment: perl 5.14.2 gave me: ```Can't locate experimental.pm``` in a script with that line and nothing else.  Am I supposed to be using something else?

Comment: @msouth are you sure you have the module installed?

Comment: Sorry @AKHolland I assumed it was in core.  My bad. You might prevent anyone else from making this incorrect assumption by editing it to read "try installing the experimental module".  I guess with the lower case and stuff I thought it was something in core I'd never heard of.  And thank you for taking the time to come back to this to answer my question!

Comment: you can 'use experimental' but directing which routines to use from it does not remove the warnings, the above response removes the print out to std.