# Hiding Warnings that Relate to Intentional Code in Perl

Tags: perl

I have several warnings like the following that show up a lot when Perl is interpreting my code:

```
 Smartmatch is experimental at /home/user/www/cgi-bin/safari/lib/SAFARI/Data.pm line 395.
```

And several from where I override a CPAN module's subroutine that contains bugs:

```
 Subroutine Net::Amazon::S3::Client::Object::put_part redefined at /usr/local/share/perl5/FaithTree/Backup.pm line 65.
```

Both of these are intentional things in the code. I've found Smartmatch a wonderful tool that I'm intentionally using without any issues and I overrode those subroutines specifically because they didn't function properly in the upstream module. Is there a "proper" way to tell Perl not to show such warnings? If there's some need for them still, is there proper way to at least rein them in so it doesn't overwhelm server logs?

I read over on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653096/perl-no-warnings-experimental-on-old-perl) that I could use `use experimental qw(smartmatch switch);` to hide the Smartmatch warning. But I'm less certain what to do about the redefinition warning.

Comment: Note that if you're monkey patching a module in a module, you should change it only for your purposes, then put the original back so other code isn't affected. [Demo](https://gist.github.com/schwern/2483dffabab4d41e1457541f5fde21ee)

Comment: I'm not sure I would describe smartmatch as a "wonderful tool".

Comment: @TLP Is there some reason to avoid smartmatch? It sure seems helpful..

Comment: @demo The patch is actually in an application -- I just put it in its own module namespace so it could be installed with MakeMaker. One of the fixes is submitted upstream already; I need to send in another bug report, too. Thanks!

Comment: @TimothyR.Butler  "_Is there some reason to avoid smartmatch?_"  --- ugh, yes; a lot's been written on that.   I'm guessing that you probably use a few basics that are clear and intuitive and not too complex, and no wonder it's likeable.  Without going into all _other_ details, the main problem is that it will almost certainly be changed, and likely quite a lot, and possibly beyond recognition -- or worse.  So all code that uses it would then have to change.

Comment: I can't stress enough that by turning off the mandatory 'experimental' warning, you as a coder are assuming full responsibility for your code failing completely, or in strange random ways, with a future release of perl.

Comment: @TimothyR.Butler Smartmatch does not do anything that you cannot do without smartmatch. Your real question should be "How do I make my code work without smartmatch", rather than the much worse alternative "How do I hide warnings from experimental features".

Comment: @TLP I suppose I should investigate that. I find it so helpful for searching arrays, primarily.

Comment: Smartmatch was deprecated recently by the Perl developers. It's scheduled to be removed from Perl entirely in Perl 5.42. See https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2022/12/msg265180.html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
use experimental qw(feature ...);
```

to use experimental features without warnings. To suppress other warnings, run your code with a `no warnings ...` pragma enabled as described in the [perldoc](https://metacpan.org/pod/warnings#DESCRIPTION)

```
no warnings 'redefine';
sub Someone::Elses::Package::my_monkey_patch_func { ... }

@c = (1, 2, undef, 4);
print join(";", @c);   # emits warning
{
    no warnings 'uninitialized';
    print join(":", @c); # warning suppressed
}
```

Comment: Note that you'll want to scope that `no warnings` to that single line, else it will apply to the entire rest of the file. `{ no warnings 'redefine'; sub ... }`.